# Can complex analysis be used to solve Laplace's equation in three dimensions?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, laplace-equation

Can complex analysis be used to solve Laplace's equation in three dimensions? Or is it restricted to cases which have 2D symmetry?

All of the examples I've seen are 2D, never 3D.

It would seem that the answer is "2D only", since the complex plane is 2D. I just want to confirm that that is indeed correct.

Comment: probably more suitable for MSE, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2750398/87355

Comment: OK. I have created https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419141/can-complex-analysis-be-used-to-solve-laplaces-equation-in-three-dimensions Please delete this question if desired.